# PHP has encountered an Access Violation at 77FCAFF8

Tags: php, windows, jquery

I am running a PHP site that uses Ajax and jQuery as well. The site will run fine for quite some time, and suddently my pages (and ajax-retrieved sub-pages) comes back with the message

> PHP has encountered an Access Violation at 77FCAFF8

It seems that rebooting the server corrects the issue. Running PHP Version 5.1.6 (Windows NT 5.0 build 2195). I did a some searching on here and some other sites, and there seems to be no fix..

**URL REMOVED**

**UPDATE:**
I think I'm on to something.. will get back to you.

**UPDATE**
After reviewing the IIS setup, i noticed there was no Handler Mapping setup for the website. This, of course begs the question - how did it ever work in the first place, when it was originally setup this way!? I added the handler mapping and it seems to be Okay so far.

**UPDATE**
The problem popped its heads out again this morning after 36 hours without encounering it. Back to the drawing board.

**UPDATE**
We ended up just moving the site to a secondary web server where we were able to upgrade PHP without an issue.

Comment: Actually I got this error several times on your site, both blank full screen with error and in one of the product(?) headings.

Comment: Having randomly selected many 'category' and 'system' I was not able to repeat this error. Probably unrelated... Selecting "Office / Commercial Intercoms" and "ITU Series Ticket Window and Service Windows Intercom" left both SELECT boxes disabled.

Comment: @MrVexxed: The site should work now that the system's been rebooted.
@w3d: Good Catch. Thanks for that.

Comment: I was about to suggest upgrading PHP (5.1.6 was released in *2006*), but you're also running Windows 2000 (NT 5.0)... you might want to consider bringing your architecture a little further into the current century.  Windows 2000 Server reaches [end of life **tomorrow**, July 13!](http://blogs.technet.com/b/windowsserver/archive/2010/01/14/windows-2000-server-approaching-end-of-life.aspx)

Comment: @Dutchie432 please do let us know if you think you've found the fix.

Comment: After reviewing the IIS setup, i noticed there was no Handler Mapping setup for the website. This, of course begs the question - how did it ever work in the first place, when it was originally setup this way!? I added the handler mapping and it seems to be Okay so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a PHP issue somewhere.  You could spend some time narrowing down which function you're using that is causing the problem.  I would instead upgrade to a newer version of PHP.  If still no luck, try a slightly older version.  There have been **significant** changes with version 5.3.2.

Comment: We've actually tried to upgrade our PHP, but have installation issues.

Comment: I really can't recall at the moment. I've even had to use external json_decode libraries to get that functionality on my sites as a result of the upgrade problems.

Comment: I awarded this as the correct answer because of the statement "This is a PHP issue somewhere." It seems to be the case, and while I haven't resolved the issue exactly, I think this is the closest we came.

Answer (score 2):

After some research I think  this may be the solution (Taken from http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=28929 ):

[2010-06-11 15:12 UTC] in2ishun at yahoo dot com
***************** SOLUTION!!!!

I realize this issue is AGES old, but it still manages to be the top hit on Google searches as of now (6/2010).

I fixed my own instance of seeing this error. W2k3, IIS6, PHP 5.2.6, MySQL 5.1.

The problem is in the pathing. When I used the MSI installer for MySQL without doing an "advanced" installation (where I could manage the install details), it added a path to the system environment that contained spaces. Even after changing the path environment to use the Windows short-name location of the mysql bin directory, it still didn't work.

The solution was for me to reinstall mysql and set the default installation path to just off the root (e.g. C:\mysql). Once I did that the error went away and my app started working.

There are a number of sites with a variety of potential solutions to this issue and several of them mentioned paths and the "libmysql.dll" file (in the "bin" directory of your mysql installation).

If this helps you solve your problem, consider leaving a comment here so others can see that it works.

Comment: "it added a path to the system environment that contained spaces" Do you think that means the windows path variable or something in the PHP ini file?

Comment: Could very well be it. Ideally if I recall the paths shouldn't contain spaces, special characters or be over a certain character limit (120?). This solution hasn't been confirmed to work in all cases though so while it is an option to attempt, it by no means is a confirmed fix.

Comment: Do you think that means the windows path variable or something in the PHP ini file?

Comment: It looks like its a MySQL Installation issue. Is it possible to uninstall and reinstall MySQL? Rinstall it and set the default installation path as C:\mysql if you can, that seemed to fix per the above solution. The overall issue is definitely a Mysql - PHP issue from what I had read. Typically PHP should be installed first followed on by MySQL. It could be an order of operations issue if you did it the opposite way.

Comment: The server doesn't even have MySQL on it.