# php and mysql connect issues on windows server / IIS6

Tags: php, mysql

I installed php and mysql on a Windows 2003 server running IIS6.  I uncommented the lines for the mysql and mysqli extensions.  I am able to run phpinfo, and am seeing the mysql and mysqli sections in phpinfo.
I then run the following code to attempt a connection to the database -

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'mypassword');
if (!$link) 
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

When I attempt to load this through a browser, I am getting a generic 500 server error.  I don't know where else to look to troubleshoot this issue.  Can someone point me in the right direction?
I am also able to access the mysql database using mysql workbench on the server.

Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: see server error log for the error message

Comment: Run it via command line and PHP will give you a better error.  I suspect that you're using one of the newer versions that does not have the mysql_* functions.

Comment: Col. Shrapnel - There are no errors in the event logs on the server.  
Fosco - the newer versions of php?  I am actually running an older version - 5.2.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by referring to this post - [PHP has encountered an Access Violation at 77FCAFF8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231571/php-has-encountered-an-access-violation-at-77fcaff8)

Ultimately, I uninstalled MySql and then reinstalled at the root of my filesystem in order to eliminate any spaces in the path.  I then recycled my application pools, and am now able to connect.

thanks.