# Specific web page started to occasionally result in 500 internal error

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess

I've come across an issue today where a specific page on my site is sometimes causing a 500 internal error. The page normally can take fairly long to load due to some database queries on large datasets, but only today has the apache 500 internal error started to happen. Obviously I will try to optimise the db queries as much as possible to improve page loading speed, but does anyone have an idea why this may have started to happen after having been fine for a couple of months? I'm not aware of any server wide configuration changes. Is it possibly a script execution time issue which needs to be modified in php.ini?

Comment: Did you check the Apache and PHP error logs?

Comment: I have pretty restricted privileges and can't view /var/log/messages, not sure where else to look, no such folder as /var/log/apache/php.errors

Comment: `phpinfo()` will show you where PHP's errors are going.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231571/php-has-encountered-an-access-violation-at-77fcaff8). Ended up having to move the site to a newer server. No resolution was found.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=28929

Answer (score 0):

without error logs its quite a guessing...

- it could be memory-limit

or

- execution time

check the php settings and change them.

since the data-value in your db is growing its normal that such problem shows up after a while. you'll have to refactoring the "page" specially your queries.